# Double free or corruption (out) on assignment operator

Tags: c++, mpi, assignment-operator

I am working on a parallel code. In my main function I have a loop over time, and at the start I need to copy the class by using the assignment operator. But somehow at 4th step, the double free or corruption error occurs on one of the processor, and others fine; and the error on std::set and set::map. Below is the part of the code and main loop.

```
    class Mesh
    {
      public:

        const Mesh &operator=(const Mesh &mesh);

        std::set<size_t> ghostSet;
        std::map<size_t, size_t> localIndex;
    }
```

Assignment operator:

```
    const Mesh &operator=(const Mesh &mesh)
    {
      std::set<size_t>().swap(ghostSet);  ///BUG here
      std::map<size_t, size_t>().swap(localIndex); /// BUG sometimes here
      for(auto const &it : mesh.localIndex)
        localIndex[it.first] = it.second;
      for(auto const &it : mesh.ghostSet)
        ghostSet.insert(it);
      return *this;
    }
```

main function:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      Mesh ms, ms_gh;
      /// Some operation to ms;
      for(size_t t = 0; t != 10; t++)
      {
        /// Some operation to ms;
        ms_gh = ms;
        /// Some operation to ms_gh;
      }
    }

    #0  0x00002aaab2405207 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
    #1  0x00002aaab24068f8 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
    #2  0x00002aaab2447cc7 in __libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6
    #3  0x00002aaab2450429 in _int_free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
    #4  0x000000000041bfba in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<unsigned long> >::deallocate (this=07fffffff8b50, __p=0x7131c0)
at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/ext/new_allocator.h:110
    #5  0x000000000041835c in std::_Rb_tree<unsigned long, unsigned long, std::_Identity<unsigned long>, std::ess<unsigned long>, std::allocator<unsigned long> >::_M_put_node (this=0x7fffffff8b50, __p=0x7131c0)
at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_tree.h:374
    #6  0x000000000041276e in std::_Rb_tree<unsigned long, unsigned long, std::_Identity<unsigned long>, std::ess<unsigned long>, std::allocator<unsigned long> >::_M_destroy_node (this=0x7fffffff8b50, __p=0x7131c0)
at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_tree.h:422
    #7  0x000000000040c8ad in std::_Rb_tree<unsigned long, unsigned long, std::_Identity<unsigned long>, std::ess<unsigned long>, std::allocator<unsigned long> >::_M_erase (this=0x7fffffff8b50, __x=0x7131c0)
at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_tree.h:1127
    #8  0x000000000040c88a in std::_Rb_tree<unsigned long, unsigned long, std::_Identity<unsigned long>, std::ess<unsigned long>, std::allocator<unsigned long> >::_M_erase (this=0x7fffffff8b50, __x=0x72f410)
at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_tree.h:1125
    #9  0x000000000040c88a in std::_Rb_tree<unsigned long, unsigned long, std::_Identity<unsigned long>, std::ess<unsigned long>, std::allocator<unsigned long> >::_M_erase (this=0x7fffffff8b50, __x=0x72b760)
at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_tree.h:1125
    #10 0x000000000040c88a in std::_Rb_tree<unsigned long, unsigned long, std::_Identity<unsigned long>, std::ess<unsigned long>, std::allocator<unsigned long> >::_M_erase (this=0x7fffffff8b50, __x=0x70fce0)
at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_tree.h:1125
    #11 0x00000000004080c4 in std::_Rb_tree<unsigned long, unsigned long, std::_Identity<unsigned long>, std::ess<unsigned long>, std::allocator<unsigned long> >::~_Rb_tree (this=0x7fffffff8b50, __in_chrg=<optimized ut>)
at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_tree.h:671
    #12 0x0000000000407bbc in std::set<unsigned long, std::less<unsigned long>, std::allocator<unsigned long> ::~set (this=0x7fffffff8b50, 
__in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_set.h:90
    #13 0x0000000000405003 in Mesh::operator= (this=0x7fffffffa8a0, mesh=...)
at mesh.cpp:73
    #14 0x000000000048eb98 in DynamicMesh::reattach_ghost (mpi_comm=1140850688, 
ms=..., cn=..., ms_gh=..., gh=..., cn_gh=..., ale=..., t=4)
at dynamicMesh.cpp:273
```

In this case the traceback #13 corresponds to swap the std::set.

My problem is why this kind of error does not appear at the first time step, and why it does not appear on all processors. Moreover, this bug sometimes occurs in the std::map related lines.

Additionally, on my macOS and Linux laptop, the code can be run successfully; but it does not work on the HPC.

Comment: Since both `std::set` and `std::map` have assignment operators, I suggest you go with [the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) and use the compilers default-generated assignment operator.

Comment: "_I am working on a parallel code_" Both `std::set`, and `std::map` are **not** thread safe. Are you synchronizing accesses to those? Since your `operator=` shows no signs of synchronization.

Comment: Oh and fix the UB you have by not returning anything from the operator function. And return a *non* constant reference.

Comment: The problem is because `ghostSet.insert(it)` should be `ghostSet.insert(*it)`.     That said, you could replace the whole body of the operator function with `{localIndex = mesh.localIndex; ghostSet = mesh.ghostSet; return *this;}` or (better) don't implement the operator at all (since the effect is the same as what a compiler will give you by default).

Comment: Your assignment operator is declared to return a const reference, which is totally meaningless. Moreover, there's no actual return statement in it. If your compiler didn't warn you, consider switching compilers. Swapping with a temporary doesn't make much sense either, you can just clear(). You can assign vectors and maps using the `=` operator, no need to write your own (inefficient) copy loop. In fact your class can ditch user-defined assignment and use the default one, as there are no unmanaged pointers in there. I doubt these iare the reasons of the crash, just to bear something in mind.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, thank you for your reply. I have fixed the return. I have used default assignment operator for std::set and set::map, and still not work; and then I changed to this complicated thing.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, each process is independent at these stages, I have petsc to manage the global synchronising.

Comment: @n.m. Thank you for your reply. I have used clear() and = operator, it does not work either. And this is just part of the class, I have to do user-defined assignment operator on other parts.

Comment: @Peter `ghostSet.insert(it)` is correct, confusingly `it` is a value not an iterator

Comment: That's [voodoo](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voodoo_programming), not engineering. `=` didn't work, let's do a little rain dance around that line. Nope, won't work either.

Comment: @shidi.yan1992 the problem isn't in the code you have posted, something else is corrupting the set/map, the crash is occurring in the code you have posted but the cause is elsewhere

Comment: There is no indication that this issue relates to MPI. Maybe it isn't even in the code you provided. Please prepare a [mcve].

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thank you for your reply. I will have a look on other parts.

Comment: @shidi.yan1992 While `std::set` or `std::map` iterators remain valid on element insertion or movement (e. g. on internal tree re-balancing), they get invalidated on deletion (which happens on clearing as well, of course). So if you hold an iterator to either set or map somewhere before assignment, make sure you don't use it any more afterwards!

Answer (score 1):

Far too complex! Step 1: Both `std::set` and `std::map` have a `clear` function, so no need for swapping with empty temporaries:

```
/* const*/ Mesh& Mesh::operator=(Mesh const& other)
// why return const? 'this' isn't const either;
// if at all, you only prevent using it directly afterwards:
// Mesh x, y;
// (x = y).someNonConstFunction();
{
    //std::set<size_t>().swap(ghostSet);  ///BUG here
    //std::map<size_t, size_t>().swap(localIndex); /// BUG sometimes here

    localIndex.clear();
    for(auto const &it : other.localIndex)
        localIndex[it.first] = it.second;

    ghostSet.clear();
    for(auto const &it : other.ghostSet)
        ghostSet.insert(it);
}
```

Re-ordering the clearing above is just for better illustration of step 2: Both `std::map` and `std::set` already provide assignment operators that do exactly what clearing and the copy loop do:

```
Mesh& Mesh::operator=(Mesh const& other)
{
    //localIndex.clear();
    //for(auto const &it : other.localIndex)
    //    localIndex[it.first] = it.second;
    localIndex = other.localIndex;


    //ghostSet.clear();
    //for(auto const &it : other.ghostSet)
    //    ghostSet.insert(it);
    ghostSet = other.ghostSet;

    // now fixing as well:
    return *this;
}
```

Step 3: Now above operator does exactly what the default assignment operator does, solely the default does assignments in the order of members being declared, so would first assign the set, then the map. Assuming assignment order being irrelevant, you finally get to:

```
class Mesh
{
    Mesh& Mesh::operator=(Mesh const& other) = default;
};
```

> I am working on a parallel code [...]

Be aware that in any case, assignments are not thread-safe (neither was your original code with loops). It is pretty likely that your double-deletion issue simply resulted from simultaneous access to either the set or map. You will have to protect your map from being accessed while the operator is yet active, e. g. via a mutex.

You have not two options: Make your class itself thread-safe by aquiring the mutex any time it is accessed (getters as well!), however, returning any contents by reference or pointer then gets unsafe as the lock won't be held any more as soon as the getter is exited. If you return by value anyway, no problem.

The other variant is leaving correct thread synchronisation to the user, which avoids above problems, as the would lock the mutex before getting a reference, hold the mutex as long as the reference is yet in use and only then release it.

Above approach could be improved with read/write locks, where the read write lock is only held if the object is modified (new items added to map or set or assignment as above). Critical is modifying single elements – one would need to hold the write lock as well unless the elements provide a mutex or similar on their own or can be modified atomically (or with some lock-free algorithm).

Comment: Thank you for your time and detailed reply. The mutex may not actually work in my case. I'm using the distributed memory and every process is independent, each process has its own set and map.

Comment: I see... Then the issue is not related to parallelism, and the initial sentence of your question is at best misleading (don't need to drop it, but keep in mind for future questions: don't provide irrelevant information).